# Apparmor doesn't work with 3.1.5-pf kernel

Tags: kernel, apparmor

I have update manually the kernel on ubuntu 11.10 and now I have this messages on boot:

```
Cache read/write disabled: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/features interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
```

The kernel version is 3.1.5 with -pf patchset and apparmor enabled in kernel config ?
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upstream kernel needs to be patched with an AppArmor compatibility patch to be able to work with the AppArmor userspace tools.

Comment: Right ! Just download the 2.7 tarball and apply the patch to bare 3.1 then -pf patchset, compile again now it's working. Thanks !

Comment: Would you mind providing links to these patches and tarballs and such so that other uses such as myself can learn from your accomplishments?  <3

Comment: http://my.opera.com/lopanrs/blog/2011/11/30/instalar-kernel-custom-no-linux-2
There's a link to apparmor patch. The blog are in Portuguese, google translate it well.